# what's the difference in meaning between an adjective and the structure "noun + of + article + noun"?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, construction

Example:

> Did you hire that *clown of a teacher*?
>
> and
>
> Did you hire that *clownish teacher*?

Or

> My *idiotic friend*
>
> and
>
> My *idiot of a friend*?

Comment: In one, you have clown for a teacher and an idiot for a friend. In the other, you have a teacher who is clownish and a friend who is idiotic.

Comment: One is a metaphor, the other is a description. "My teacher is a clown" is not meant to be literal. "My teacher acts like a clown" (a clownish teacher) is a factual description.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two variants of each example you give are more or less synonyms, but the structures with *of a* are more informal and convey more about the person who uses it.

***Of a*** is an idiom which can also be combined with other parts of speech, not only with nouns:

> US, *informal*
> —used to indicate that someone or something is a particular type of person or thing:
>
> - her *idiot **of a** husband* [noun + of a + noun]
> - It is not *that much **of a** problem*. [adverb + of a + noun]
> - How *big **of a** piece* do you want? [adjective + of a + noun] ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/of%20a))

As for *clownish teacher* and *my idiotic friend*, they are less informal and more neutral. The structures with ***of a*** also point to feelings in the speaker such as anger, irony, irritation. It can also express positive feelings like admiration:

> - an angel of a girl [an angelic girl]
> - a beauty of a woman [a beautiful woman]
> - a mountain of a man [a man as tall as a mountain]

Comment: A son of a gun?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Good one! I like the one with "hell" which can be both negative and positive, depending on context: "a hell of a story" can be a hellish story, or an awesome story :)

Comment: The 'of a' in the question refers to subsetting, 'an "angel type" of girl', '[not] that large a size of a problem'. I suppose 'son of a gun' was originally a related usage, 'son: subset: born at sea / between cannons'. A 'gun of a son' speaks more of possession.